Django filtering by annotated field
I'm trying to sort only those objects that contain arrays in the JSON field
class Rule(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField()

class JsonbTypeof(Func):
    function = 'jsonb_typeof'

Rule.objects.annotate(type=JsonbTypeof("data")).filter(type="array")
But this query always returns an empty queryset
However, if you call
Rule.objects.annotate(type=JsonbTypeof("data")).values("type")
then the expected queryset with a set of objects is returned:
<QuerySet [{'type': 'object'}, {'type': 'object'}, {'type': 'array'}, {'type': 'array'}]>
And if you do like this:
Rule.objects.annotate(type=Value("array")).filter(type="array")
Then the filtering is done correctly
Are there any experts who can tell me how to filter and leave only arrays?

What does print(Rule.objects.annotate(type=JsonbTypeof("data")).filter(type="array").query) print?

  "analysis_rule"."id", 
  jsonb_typeof("analysis_rule"."data") AS "type", 
FROM 
  "analysis_rule" 
WHERE 
  jsonb_typeof("analysis_rule"."data") = "array"```

does that return results when you run the query in the postgresql database?

Yes, but only if I change the quotes around the word "array"
`SELECT
"analysis_rule"."id",
jsonb_typeof("analysis_rule"."data") AS "type"
FROM
"analysis_rule"
WHERE
jsonb_typeof("analysis_rule"."data") = 'array'`

what if you add output_field = CharField() to your JsonbTypeof class?

@SergeyM double quotes are used for names of tables / fields, although that's probably just Django not printing the query probably The "array" would have actually been sent separately as a parameter. Is that your entire queryset or is there more to your query?

@willeM_VanOnsem yes, with the field type specified the result is correct, queriset contains data. thank you. leave an answer, i will choose it as a solution

You can specify the output field:
from django.db.models import CharField


class JsonbTypeof(Func):
    function = 'jsonb_typeof'
    output_field = CharField()
such that Django knows it has to handle it as a string.
